# checking account reconcile formula with positive and negative numbers

Tags: javascript

Can't seem to get the simply math formula for reconcile to  equal zero. 
Here is the function that I am using. Using simple number to test this out and it is not working. 
startbalance 0.00, endbalance  200.00, vals 200.00 = two entries +100 and +100, chg 0.00, endBal should equal 0 however it keeps coming up with a positive 200.

```
function addRecon(item){

    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('deposit[]');
    var vals = 0;
    var invSelect1 = ""; 
    for (var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
        {
            vals = vals + parseFloat(checkboxes[i].value);
            invSelect1 += ","+checkboxes[i].id;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('curDeposits').innerHTML = '$ '+vals.toFixed(2);

    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('withdrawl[]');
    var chg = 0;
    var invSelect2 = ""; 
    for (var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
        {
            chg = chg + parseFloat(checkboxes[i].value);
            invSelect2 += ","+checkboxes[i].id;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('curWithdrawls').innerHTML = '$ '+chg.toFixed(2);

    var startBalance = document.getElementsByName('startbalance').value; 
    var endBalance = document.getElementsByName('endbalance').value;
    startBalance = ~~parseFloat(startBalance);  
    endBalance = ~~parseFloat(endBalance); 


    var balEnd = 0;
    balEnd = startBalance + vals - chg - endBalance;

    document.getElementById('curBal').innerHTML = '$ '+balEnd.toFixed(2); 

}



<div class="x_panel">
              <div class="x_title">
                <div class="row">
                <h2>Reconcile</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label>Start Balance</label>
                        <h3><?=number_money($startbalance);?></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label>Deposits</label>
                        <h3 id="curDeposits"><?=number_money(0.00);?></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label>Withdrawls</label>
                        <h3 id="curWithdrawls"><?=number_money(0.00);?></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label>Ending Balance</label>
                        <h3 id="endBalance"><?=number_money($endbalance);?></h3>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label>Reconcile Balance</label>
                        <h3 id="curBal"><?=number_money($startbalance-$endbalance)?></h3>    
                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="x_content">
              <? //print_r($frm); ?>
              <form action="reconcile.php" method="POST" id="reconForm">
                <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="complete" id="mode" />
                <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="<?=$userID?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="co" value="<?=$co?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="account" value="<?=$account;?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="startbalance" value="<?=$startbalance;?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="startdate" value="<?=$startdate;?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="endbalance" value="<?=$endbalance;?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="enddate" value="<?=$enddate;?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="debitAdd" value="" id="debitAdd"/>


                <script>

                    function addRecon(item){

                      var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('deposit[]');
                      var vals = 0;
                      var invSelect1 = ""; 
                      for (var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
                            if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
                                    {
                                        vals = vals + parseFloat(checkboxes[i].value);
                                        invSelect1 += ","+checkboxes[i].id;
                                    }
                            }

                        document.getElementById('curDeposits').innerHTML = '$ '+vals.toFixed(2);

                      var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('withdrawl[]');
                      var chg = 0;
                      var invSelect2 = ""; 
                      for (var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
                            if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
                                    {
                                        chg = chg + parseFloat(checkboxes[i].value);
                                        invSelect2 += ","+checkboxes[i].id;
                                    }
                            }

                        document.getElementById('curWithdrawls').innerHTML = '$ '+chg.toFixed(2);

                        var startBalance = document.getElementsByName('startbalance').value; 
                        var endBalance = document.getElementsByName('endbalance').value;
                        startBalance = ~~parseFloat(startBalance);  
                        endBalance = ~~parseFloat(endBalance); 


                        var balEnd = 0;
                        balEnd = startBalance + vals - chg - endBalance;

                        document.getElementById('curBal').innerHTML = '$ '+balEnd.toFixed(2); 


                    }

                </script>


               <div class="">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="x_panel">
              <div class="x_title">
                <h2><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i> Reconcile Account: <?=$account;?> <small></small></h2>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="x_content">

                <div class="" role="tabpanel" data-example-id="togglable-tabs">
                  <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs bar_tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab_content1" id="home-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Deposits</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#tab_content2" role="tab" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Withdrawls</a>
                    </li>

                  </ul>
                  <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab_content1" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                  <table id="datatable-keytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th>Date</th>
                       <th>Ref</th>
                       <th>Description<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc pull-right"></i></a></th>
                       <th>Amount</th>
                       <th><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></th>


                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <? //print_r($deposit);
                   echo "endbalance:".$endbalance;
                   echo "startbalance:".$startbalance;
                  for($a=0;$a<count($deposit); $a++){ ?>
                     <tr>
                        <td><?=retrieve_date($deposit[$a]['enterdate']);?></td>
                        <td><?=$deposit[$a]['reference'];?></td>
                        <td><?=$deposit[$a]['memo'];?></td>
                        <td><?=number_money($deposit[$a]['debit']);?></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="deposit[]" id="<?=$deposit[$a]['transid'];?>" value="<?=$deposit[$a]['debit'];?>" onclick="addRecon(this);"/></td>

                     </tr>  

                  <? } ?>



                  </table>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_content2" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                      <table id="datatable-keytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th>Date</th>
                       <th>Ref</th>
                       <th>Description<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc pull-right"></i></a></th>
                       <th>Amount</th>
                       <th><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></th>


                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                   <? print_r($withdrawl); 
                  for($a=0;$a<count($withdrawl); $a++){ ?>
                     <tr>
                        <td><?=retrieve_date($withdrawl[$a]['enterdate']);?></td>
                        <td><?=$withdrawl[$a]['reference'];?></td>
                        <td><?=$withdrawl[$a]['memo'];?></td>
                        <td><?=number_money($withdrawl[$a]['credit']);?></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="withdrawl[]" id="<?=$withdrawl[$a]['transid'];?>" value="<?=$withdrawl[$a]['credit'];?>" onclick="addRecon(this);"/></td>

                     </tr>  

                  <? } ?>


                  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementsByName returns collections of elements, 
 please refer below link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName, so whereever you have used getElementsByName for value , it should be document.getElementsByName('startbalance')[0]